# syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, assets

apparently I am getting an error that is expecting an RPAREN somewhere (Line 12). However I checked all of the parens by hand and they are balanced. Does anybody see what I am missing?

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
  font-family:"Apollo MT W02 Italic";
  src:url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/font.eot?#iefix')%>); /*line 11*/
  src:url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/font.eot?#iefix')%>) format("eot"),url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/font.woff")%>) format("woff"),url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/font.ttf")%>) format("truetype"),url(<%=font_path("/assets/fonts/font.svg#font")%>) format("svg");
}
@font-face{
  font-family:"Univers LT W02 55 Roman";
  src:url(<%=font_path("/assets/fonts/font.eot?#iefix")%>);
  src:url(<%=font_path("/assets/fonts/font.eot?#iefix")%>)     format("eot"),url(<%=font_path("/assets/fonts/font.woff")%>) format("woff"),url(<%=font_path("/assets/fonts/font.ttf")%>) format("truetype"),url(<%=font_path("/assets/fonts/font.svg#font")%>) format("svg");
} 
</style>
```

Comment: it's not a missing parent but improperly paired single-quote to quote: `url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/font.woff")%>) ` You can see it if you look at the code highlighting in the editor.

Comment: single quote to start a string, double quote to end it.... not once but twice in that one line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just typo:

You have opened single quotes and closed double qoutes.

```
... format("eot"),url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/font.woff")%>)
                                                           ^
```

and it should be

```
... format("eot"),url(<%=font_path('/assets/fonts/font.woff')%>)
                                                           ^
```

Answer (score 3):

You're starting some of your strings with single quotes and finishing them with doubles, e.g.:

```
'/assets/fonts/font.woff"
```

Change these to be consistent (either all single or all double for each string).

Comment: what is best practice, single quotes or double quotes in this context?